# Can I replace a drop-in sink with a counter-top mounted sink?

Tags: sink, load-bearing, vanity

Would it work to remove a drop-in sink and replace it with a top mounted sink?

I'm thinking that now work would need to be done to the counters themselves besides attaching the new sink. The original hole for the drop-in sink would be covers by the new sink.

Are there any problems with this plan?

The final project would look something like this:

[image: this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al long as it covers the old cutout and the original top is strong enough to carry the weight, there will be no problem. Vessel sinks are usually held in place by the drain to a degree and sealed at the base with a good grade of caulk. Yours is heavy enough, if it is the same bulk as the one pictured, its weight alone will keep it in place, but please seal it down with a good water based, mildew proof caulk.

Comment: +1 But note that it will be much higher than the original.

Comment: I would hope that would go without saying. In one custom home we built, the architect that designed a master bath with 34" tall cabinets and vessel sinks, man that was really awkward using the sinks, the top of the sinks were above the elbows making it difficult to use.

Comment: @Jack I feel like my sink is awkwardly low (30"). I don't plan to install something nearly as large, but this was the best picture I could find quickly.

Comment: @itsjustluck If you installed a vessel sink like the one pictured, or similar at about 6-7" tall that would work very well for a Master bath. If it was for a hall bath  where kids use it that is where a problem occur even with a 30" height to start with.